# Looping through a multidimensional boolean array

Tags: java

I want to know how to loop through a multidimensional array where I will check if all of its values are true.

```
public static boolean arrayTrue(boolean[][] array) {
    for (boolean b : array)
        if(!b) return false;
    return true;
}
```

this is what I am using but it seems to be only functional if its a 1D array can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: Using classic for loop**

```
for(int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j< array[i].length; j++) {
        if(! array[i][j]) return false;
    }
}
return false;
```

**Option 2: Using for each loop** (see @Scary Wombat's answer)

```
for (boolean[] bb : array) {
   for (boolean b : bb) {
     if(!b) return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 4):

change to

```
for (boolean[] bb : array) {
    for (boolean b : bb) {
        if(!b) return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

so that you can loop through the 2D array

Comment: @jai Cheers - Fixed